# xcode 4.2 TTImageView in UIScrollView, views don't appear in Released iTunes version but do in Debug

Tags: xcode, three20, ios5

I have a project that I started a while ago with xcode 3 that displays search results as TTImageViews in a UIScrollView. I updated to xcode 4.2 recently and managed to successfully build and archive the project for submitting to the app store. The scroll view worked fine on the simulator and on the phone in debug mode. The app was approved and I downloaded the update. Only 3 TTImageView objects display where there should be pages of them. The scrollview is sized properly.

First time I used the version of three20 I had and used Product->Archive and submitted through Organizer. Three TTImageViews displayed.

Second time I used latest version of three20, and used Product->Archive and submitted through Organizer. Three TTImageViews displayed, again.

Third time I used latest version of three20, and used Product->Build For->Build for Archive and compressed and submitted the app using application loader. Two pages of 9 TTImageViews display.

All the time works fine in the simulator and on the phone with DEBUG configuration.

Any idea what is happening here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.